# how to register custom PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in spring 3.0

Tags: spring, orm, jpa

I´d like to override the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor which gets registered as soon as I insert a context:component-scan tag.

I tried to register a bean with the same name, but spring still registers the original postprocessor bean.

My goal is to provide an overriden version of findDefaultEntityManager method which will alow me to declare two EntityManagers in the same container.

Note: I have the 2 EM context running on spring 2.5.6, but it gets broken when migrated to 3.0.5.RELEASE version.

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken'? Can you post stacktrace/errors?

Comment: Sure,
by bronken I mean that since i moved to spring 3.0 it throws an exception telling me that there are two entityManagersFactory instances when i try to start tomcat server.

The exception is throwed at findDefaultEntityManagerFactory method of PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class, at line 536 (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException "expected single bean but found 2")

I´ll post the full stack here soon (don´t have it right now), but i think that its enough information anyway if you have the spring-orm code.

Comment: I don't know if this might be useful, but I know that Spring 3 is supposed to manage than one EM far better than before (specially the transactional support). It could be that you need to change some of the configuration as probably it got replaced with some new beans... again, just a note/idea.

Comment: indeed. I´ll make some research. tks.

Answer (score 8):

I found this workaround has worked for me ( Spring 3.2.7):

```
<bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" >
<property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This would override the default PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor loaded by Spring with a new one with defaultPersistenceUnitName. You **have** to use the bean name Spring used when automatically loaded this bean (which is the default behaviour). I had to look into org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors() to figure out this name.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the `unitName` attribute of your `@PersistenceUnit`/`@PersistenceContext` annotations?
Since the [javaDoc of PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) says it is supported...

Comment: beacause i have DAOs in a framework that can be used in different projects, with different ems.

Comment: @luiz: Then you might want to inject the LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean in your DAOs, instead of the annotations... This way, each project could define its own EM with the appropriate unit, eg with a placeholder.