# spring persistence annotation bean specify default persistence unit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an existing project which currently has 1 entity manager and I need to add another for a seperate data source. The entity manager is defined in spring xml application context and wired in as

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

When I wire in my other entity manager on start up spring complains because it expects a single bean but finds two because I have not defined unitname on my original entity manager. Thus the findDefaultEntityManagerFactory is always called.

**I dont want to go and amend the @PersistenceContext annotation and add unit name to all of them this is not an option.**

So the way around this after searching seems to be to define a defaultPersistenceUnitName which is in the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class. Reading the comments on this class there is a note as follows

```
<p>Note: A default PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered
 * by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags.
 * Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you intend
 * to specify a custom PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition.
```

So my question is as follows:

1. How do i turn off the default annotation configuration as in the note above? Does this mean just remove it from the xml? if I remove it how will i autowire all my other classes
2. What happens if the context:annotation-config is not in the spring xml file that defines the entity manager but is in one that is imported into this file? DO I need to remove it from there too?

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is here .. :-) .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182844/how-to-register-custom-persistenceannotationbeanpostprocessor-in-spring-3-0

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182844/how-to-register-custom-persistenceannotationbeanpostprocessor-in-spring-3-0 answers my question

Thanks